# Insert to cassandra from python using cql

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

I'm planning to insert data to bellow CF that has compound keys.

```
CREATE TABLE event_attend (
    event_id int,
    event_type varchar,
    event_user_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id, event_type)    #compound keys...
);
```

But I can't insert data to this CF from python using cql.
(http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-dbapi2/)

```
import cql
connection = cql.connect(host, port, keyspace)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO event_attend (event_id, event_type, event_user_id) VALUES (1, 'test', 2)", dict({}) )
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./v2_initial.py", line 153, in <module>
  db2cass.execute()
File "./v2_initial.py", line 134, in execute
  cscursor.execute("insert into event_attend (event_id, event_type, event_user_id ) values (1, 'test', 2)", dict({}))
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cql-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/cql/cursor.py", line 80, in execute
  response = self.get_response(prepared_q, cl)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cql-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/cql/thrifteries.py", line 80, in get_response
  return self.handle_cql_execution_errors(doquery, compressed_q, compress)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cql-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/cql/thrifteries.py", line 98, in handle_cql_execution_errors
  raise cql.ProgrammingError("Bad Request: %s" % ire.why)
cql.apivalues.ProgrammingError: Bad Request: unable to make int from 'event_user_id'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to follow the example in:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cql/1.4.0

```
import cql
con = cql.connect(host, port, keyspace)
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("CQL QUERY", dict(kw='Foo', kw2='Bar', kwn='etc...'))
```

However, if you only need to insert one row (like in your question), just drop the empty dict() parameter.

Also, since you are using composite keys, make sure you use CQL3
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cql-3-0

```
connection = cql.connect('localhost:9160', cql_version='3.0.0')
```

The following code should work (just adapt it to localhost if needed):

```
import cql
con = cql.connect('172.24.24.24', 9160,  keyspace, cql_version='3.0.0')
print ("Connected!")
cursor = con.cursor()
CQLString = "INSERT INTO event_attend (event_id, event_type, event_user_id) VALUES (131, 'Party', 3156);"
cursor.execute(CQLString)
```

Comment: Thanks Oren.
I tried to edit my code and execute, so it worked!

Comment: is there a way to bulk upload the data using same?

Answer (score 0):

For python 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6 for installation you can use

```
     $ pip install cassandra-driver
```

And in python:

```
     import cassandra
```

Documentation can be found under https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#passing-parameters-to-cql-queries

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer doesn't answer the question