# How do I execute Cassandra CLI commands from a Python script?

Tags: python, cassandra, subprocess, command-line-interface

I have a python script that I want to use to make remote calls on a server, connect to Cassandra CLI, and execute commands to create keyspaces.  One of the attempts that I made was something to this effect:

```
connect="cassandra-cli -host localhost -port 1960;"
create_keyspace="CREATE KEYSPACE someguy;"
exit="exit;"

final = Popen("{}; {}; {}".format(connect, create_keyspace, exit), shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
stdout, nothing = final.communicate()
```

Looking through various solutions, I'm not finding what I need.  For example, the above code is throwing a "/bin/sh: 1: CREATE: not found", which I *think* means that it's not executing the CREATE statement on the CLI command line.

Any/all help would be GREATLY appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: You're executing CREATE as a command line command. I'm guessing you should be feeding the CREATE command into standard in.

Comment: I know you asked for CLI but if you wish you can also try and work with this CQL module: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cql/1.4.0. Simple code example is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217434/insert-to-cassandra-from-python-using-cql/13223488#13223488

Answer (score 1):

try this out. I don't have cassandra-cli installed on my machine, so I couldn't test it myself.

```
from subprocess import check_output
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
CASSANDRA_CMD = 'cassandra-cli -host localhost -port 1960 -f '

def cassandra(commands):
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
        f.write(';\n'.join(commands))
        f.flush()
        return check_output(CASSANDRA_CMD + f.name, shell=True)

cassandra(['CREATE KEYSPACE someguy', 'exit'])
```

As you mentioned in the comment below [pycassa a Python client for Cassandra](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/) cannot be used since it doesn't seem to support create statements.

Comment: Good pointers - I'm going to invoke the pycassa client, avoiding any piping.  (it's where I started, then wavered away from)  Thank you!

sys = SystemManager('localhost:9160')
sys.create_keyspace('someguy', SIMPLE_STRATEGY, {'replication_factor': '1'})
sys.close()

Comment: I updated the answer. I'm quite certain this should work. It's using their -f option which is in their documentation